# Can I change my Flutter/iOS/Android App version dynamically during build?

Tags: ios, flutter, versioning, fastlane, codemagic

I want to push 2 app versions of my Flutter app in the App Store Connect. One is my actual release and one is my backup. They are technically the same app version. They should both be a release/production version and not dev or testing versions.

My release app has e.g the version 3.5.0. and my backup should be version 4.0.0 or 3.6.0.

I want to do this automatically for example when I push something on my master branch. Maybe I can do this via fastlane, codemagic or even a flavor?

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you want the 4.0 to actually be a build of your previous release in case you need to "roll back"?

Comment: Exactly I couldn't find a way to roll back in App Store Connect. I'll take any other suggestions.

Comment: Testing via TestFlight? Staged rollout?  Simply submitting a new version if you have a bad release? You can request expedited review if it is really urgent but app review typically takes between 1 and 24 hours.

Comment: In my case I want to be able to provide a new Version very fast. Like When I know something doesn't work I can immediately get the old Version in the Appstore. Just by clicking a few buttons in App Store Connect because I have my old build with a newer version number already up there.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's now how it is on App Store. You have to go through the review process again, which can take minutes to multiple days and anything in between. 

What you are looking for is feature flagging; if something that doesn't work out, you can switch off and go back to the old feature on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push two different builds to App Store Connect, since Version and Build Number are variables injected into multiple points in the iOS .ipa

I would setup two codemagic flows, where you can set it via  --build-name and --build-number flags for the flutter build command.

If you don't want to use codemagic, just write a script that runs the build command with the flags and into different output directories.

Comment: But then I would have to hard code the version in the codemagic flow right? I can't do something like --build-name ${VERSION +1)

Comment: Version Build Number needs to be hardcoded at one point. You could make your script read the pubspec.yaml and change it everytime you run it or based on arguments to the script. The second buildnumber/version then could be incremtend by the desired amout. It possilble in code magic to run custom scripts before the build step.

Comment: Lets say I have 3.5.0 as the version hardcoded. How could I access this in my Codemagic script?

Comment: Write a bash script. use sed to change the file before the build. Get the desired offset for the build version from an enviroment variable that you can set in codemagic. You can run custom bash at different points in a code magic pipeline.

Comment: Did it work out? @Valentin

Comment: Im working on other things for now, but I will let you know and accept your answer if it worked.